# Admob on Java Desktop app?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a program for Windows Desktop and I need to implement a ad service. I have seen that exists Admob for Android. Is any existing similar service for Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read documentation properly and they have different services for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

AdMmob is meant for Online-Ads.
As far as I know, it is not possible, to use Admob with normal Java.
Although I know, that there is AdSense for javascript.
Maybe you can find a way to do it like that.

Comment: Thanks I will take that into account :)